# VirtualBox USB - should I install drivers for USB devices on Host as well?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox

I am running a Windows XP guest on a Windows 7 host via VirtualBox.

I want to use a USB scanner on the Windows XP guest. I will not be using the scanner on the Windows 7 host itself.

The question is whether to install a driver on the Windows 7 host for the scanner, so that I don't keep getting the annoying **device driver software was not successfully installed** silliness *when not running the Windows XP guest*.

Will installing a driver on the host affect Virtual Box's ability to reliably claim the scanner for the guest when it needs it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to lack of answers I have done my own extensive testing.

**gronostaj** is correct that drivers are not required on the host in order to use them in a Virtual Machine. However that didn't quite answer the question.

My testing has confirmed that you can install USB device drivers on the Host, and doing so does not prevent VirtualBox from being able to claim the devices when needed. I tested:

- Canon 9000F Scanner
- Logitech C170 Webcam
- Logitech F310 Gamepad
- Roland UA-1G Audio Interface
- Brother HL-2250DN Printer

For each device above I installed drivers on the Host. I then created a Virtual Machine and asked VirtualBox to connect each device to that Virtual Machine. VirtualBox had no trouble claiming the devices.

Answer (score 0):

**No drivers are needed on the host.**

Actually, VirtualBox has to load its own driver for a device to be able to "connect it" to virtual machine. This driver works with any USB device.

I am 100% positive about this. I have once used an old scanner in a Windows XP guest, even though no drivers were available for Windows 7 host or even for x64 systems.

Comment: True - but my problem is that when I'm not running the Windows XP guest, the Host sees the scanner and complains that no driver has been installed for it.

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't verify it right now, but I think that when you try to install drivers through Device Manager and it fails, there's a "Don't try to install drivers again" checkbox.